# SQL Server query errors log

Tags: php, error-handling, logging, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm creating an app with PHP and SQL Server, I prefer to work with logs, and have just some general information to users in case of error, like a error number defined by me in case of possible known error, and date. but this gives me allots of problems to debug, i have found the PHP log (php-erros.log) very useful and all the errors i get i can see them pretty easy and fast without messing with the code to debug. But i still have the problem with SQL Server, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server (10.50.1600.1), I have found some log files (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log`) but these are only have main errors and i can't see errors from PHP queries, is there any way to activate or to check on those errors easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" error is not a SQL Server one but PHP.

Can we see your code?

You are trying to fetch data from a failing request. Here is a proper way to work and see what's happend:

```
<?php

$serverName = "serverName\instanceName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );


if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

This piece of code:

```
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

is what you need: testing the request result before trying to fetch it, and dumping the error.
If you want to send the SQL error to the PHP log you can use the function [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.error-log.php).

Answer (score 1):

Turn on PHP error reporting, place this at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: i don't want php errors, with that i get on php-errors.log the same: "sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given "

what i want is the sql error without the need to mess with the code , i want something like php-errors.log but for MSSQL. is it possible?

Comment: I'll take that as a no. I will use, in my case "sqlsrv_errors", to check for errors, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This topic shows how to configure the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv drivers for logging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296188.aspx. You'll also need to set the log_errors and error_log settings in your php.ini file.